# Differentiate Users in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I am learning the Django framework.

I have two groups of users: manager and employees.

At the login page, I want to differentiate between these two groups.

If the employee has logged in, then redirect it to the homepage, and if the manager logged in, redirect it to the '/manage' page.

How should I do this in Django?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What have you tried? Please [edit]
your question (do *not* add comments) and provide your code as a [mcve].
What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?
Include any error messages and stack traces.
You may want to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the user group in you login view :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at your AccountAdapter... in your ALLAUTH settings in settings.py set

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'apps.your_app_file.AccountAdapter'
```

Then in the your_app_file.py:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):  
        if request.user.profile.manager:   #or however else you can check
            return '/manager_homepage'
        else:
            return '/employee_homepage'
```

Comment: OP didn't mention he was using django-allauth... It's a 3rd party module, not included with vanilla Django setup

Comment: Oh yes, apologies. This is ONLY for those using django-allauth.